# How to properly call singleton class on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, singleton, shared

I have a singleton class named `AppSettingsController` with a few methods.

Generaly I call them like that:

```
[[AppSettingsController sharedInstance] myMethod];
```

And that's just fine.

This is how instance is created:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static AppSettingsController *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

But I am considering something else. Let's assume I have to call myMethod in a loop. Wouldn't be better to create a local variable of this singleton and call this method with this variable?

```
AppSettingsController *mySharedInstance = [AppSettingsController sharedInstance];
loop
  [mySharedInstance myMethod];
```

... instead of calling it directly?

```
loop
  [[AppSettingsController sharedInstance] myMethod];
```

Which way is more efficient or are both equal?

Comment: Any specific reason for this?

Comment: I am just curious which is better way.

Comment: I prefer to create class method, so it'll be [AppSettingsController mymethod];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[AppSettingsController sharedInstance] myMethod];` code will call two methods in a loop

and

> AppSettingsController *mySharedInstance = [AppSettingsController sharedInstance];
>   
> loop
>   [mySharedInstance myMethod];

will call only one

Here in 2nd case you are saving a single method call and thus 2nd one is more efficient. Also if in you `sharedInstance` method you have say `4` more method calls and some initialisation statements, then in that case you are saving that calls and initialisation statements too.

---

**Update**

Writing the sudo assembly code (using Sudo assembler :P). Just understand the idea don't go for exact assembly code

```
Case 1:
Loop start:
1 Call method sharedInstance

  [this code step 2-7 will be called only once]
  2 Create a static AppSettingsController *sharedInstance = nil; in sharedInstance method
  3 Create static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  4 Call dispatch_once
  5 Now dispatch_once takes lock of onceToken (and other task which is not visible for me)
  6 Call [self alloc]
  7 Call [self init]

8 Return from sharedInstance
9 Call myMethod
Loop ends:




Case 2:
1 Call method sharedInstance
2 Create a static AppSettingsController *sharedInstance = nil; in sharedInstance method
3 Create static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
4 Call dispatch_once
5 Now dispatch_once takes lock of onceToken (and other task which is not visible for me)
6 Call [self alloc]
7 Call [self init]
8 Return from sharedInstance
9 Assign sharedInstance value to mySharedInstance variable
Loop starts:
10 Call myMethod
Loop Ends:
```

Here clearly you can see what are you saving

Comment: So you are saying that option with local instance is actually more efficient?

Comment: it's not a local **instance**, but a local reference to the shared instance.

Comment: @fguchelaar yeah it's a local variable. So where is the confusion ?

Comment: BorutTomazin and Andrea Lufino both speak about local 'instances', which they are not. No confusion on my side, however :)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it's a theoretical discussion for most cases - you won't feel the performance hit of having one level of indirection more when the sharedInstance is accessed every time in the loop instead of only once for setting a local variable before the loop.

Use the version you like most (readability wise) or if you do care about the performance hit then use the local variable way.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion is better the first thing you do :

```
[[AppSettingsController sharedInstance] myMethod];
```

It is a singleton because it doesn't need to an instance. So, the first way is better. I think create an instance could use more memory than the direct call, but i'm not sure of this.

Comment: Yeah, I would think that too. But I am not sure cos whenever you call sharedInstance the code before dispatch_once is called...

Comment: There is no code called in the sharedInstance call before disptach_once - it's only static variable declarations ...

Answer (score 1):

Go for second call

```
[[AppSettingsController sharedInstance] myMethod];
```

as this way is used by world and is more readable.

Comment: Now I'm confused. @Inder-Kumar-Rathore says the first one is more efficient... ?!?

Comment: Even I am not sure :p Let some big guns see your code and comment. What I see and used is this, so I feel this as better.